# Plastic platform for THT electrolytic capacitor?

Tags: capacitor

SMD capacitor looks like this

[image]

I did not see "plastic platform" to be sold separately.

But I want such to put under THT capacitor

[image]

so that it looks like exactly the way as quarts crystal with the gasket

[image]

[image]

I just like the way it looks, mechanically holds the the electrolytic capacitor, and separates the cap from the other components.

Does such technique exist for THT electrolytic caps?

**Update:**

I desoldered one of the SMD caps of the required size, and compared the constructions and tried to put THT cap in:

[image]

Both models appeared to be covered by the protective material, but up to different point at the bottom - SMD cap is required to be put into the platform/spacer. I also see that it is bad idea to put vias or anything else conductive under the THT cap as it has very small exposed area (however risk of shorting is minimal, just to be sure and have a "good practice").

[image]

Putting the THT cap into the SMD cap's spacer has failed: THT is having rubber protruding at the bottom, effectively eliminating bottom of the capacitor seating onto the conductors. However, per datasheet, it is only for some packages:

[image]

Smaller sizes are having flat rubber, and must be able to seat into the repsective spacer salvaged from SMD cap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for "spacer" or "capacitor spacer". They exist.

[image]

[image]

Sources [here](https://www.mac8japan.com/products/340) and [here](https://www.ettinger.de/en/product/70.09.530). Can't say as I've noticed them being very common in the wild, however.

They would probably need to be made from a decent plastic to withstand wave soldering and solvent cleaning. For careful and fast hand soldering you might be able to 3-D print a suitable shape- be sure to pick a material that meets electrical and fire safety requirements if you try that.

Comment: +1 These were more common in the past with hand stuffed boards that had less reliable solder resist on the top traces.  The spacer would prevent the case of the capacitor shorting out if the capacitor wrapper and the solder mask both failed and the capacitor was bent over.  In large volume through hole designs you usually see the capacitor leads elaborately formed to raise the capacitor from the board.  Flux washing with funny spacers is also a problem.  Most often you see these spacers with uninsulated metal  transistor cans that can short out tracks easier.

Comment: I remember seeing them on TO-5 transistors and metal can TO-99 chips. Mostly before even my time. Some of the cap parts may be intended to stabilize the cap in a high vibration environment (eg. automotive) better (by some metric, not necessarily mechanical) than standing it off and/or slathering on the common gunk or silicone adhesive.